# I have the error Module '"@sveltejs/kit"' has no exported member 'error'.js(2305) even though sveltejs/kit is installed

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to follow [the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/errors) to make an error page. I confirm that the package is installed in dev dependencies:

```
// in package.json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sveltejs/adapter-vercel": "^1.0.0-next.50",
    "@sveltejs/kit": "next",   // see here
    "@testing-library/svelte": "^3.1.0",
    "@tsconfig/svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.17.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
    "c8": "^7.11.0",
    "cssnano": "^5.1.7",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-svelte3": "^3.4.1",
    "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
    "mdsvex": "^0.10.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "postcss-load-config": "^3.1.4",
    "postcss-nested": "^5.0.6",
    "postcss-simple-vars": "^6.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "prettier-plugin-svelte": "^2.6.0",
    "svelte": "^3.49.0",
    "svelte-check": "^2.4.6",
    "svelte-preprocess": "^4.10.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "vitest": "^0.8.4",
    "vitest-svelte-kit": "0.0.6"
  },
```

But when I try to import from it

```
<script>
  import { error } from "@sveltejs/kit"
</script>

<h1>The test page</h1>
```

I get `Module '"@sveltejs/kit"' has no exported member 'error'.js(2305)` even though thats what the docs say to do to import the error function.

I tried `npm update @sveltejs/kit` thinking maybe the package was out of date but nope, no change.

There is [some talk](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2384) about this being a common problem, possibly a bug; they have the same or a similar error msg as me in that post. But I don't see any other mentions of this issue, which makes me think its me.

I tried doing `npm upgrade` but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided, you're not on the latest version of Sveltekit and this is causing the issue. Take a read through the migration guide here https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/discussions/5774 and you may have to do some other items discussed in there, depending on how outdated your project is.

Comment: Am I really? How can you tell?

Comment: your package.json lists: 

 "@sveltejs/kit": "next",

and the latest version shows:

"@sveltejs/kit": "^1.0.0",